# Linking warning in protobuf-c

Tags: build, protocol-buffers, llvm, linker-errors, protobuf-c

**The build script:**

```
if [  -f ${PWD_PATH}/succeed/protobuf-c ]; then
    echo "git clone https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.git"
    eval "git clone https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.git"
    eval 'cd protobuf-c && git checkout v1.4.0 && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make -j$(nproc) && sudo  make install'
    eval 'sudo ln -sf /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libprotobuf-c.so.1'
    echo "done" > ${PWD_PATH}/succeed/protobuf-c
fi

echo
echo -e "${GREEN}[*] build protobuf-c succeed!${NC}"
```

while building protobuf-c it shows the following warning.
How can I resolve it? what specific changes should be made to the build script?

```
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   protobuf-c/libprotobuf-c.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c protobuf-c/.libs/libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0 libprotobuf-c.so.1 || { rm -f libprotobuf-c.so.1 && ln -s libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0 libprotobuf-c.so.1; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/lib && { ln -s -f libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0 libprotobuf-c.so || { rm -f libprotobuf-c.so && ln -s libprotobuf-c.so.1.0.0 libprotobuf-c.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c protobuf-c/.libs/libprotobuf-c.lai /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c protobuf-c/.libs/libprotobuf-c.a /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf-c.a
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a warning, it is just an informational message.

```
Libraries have been installed in:
   /usr/local/lib
..
- have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
```

This is generally the right place to install locally compiled libraries, and you can just check that it is present in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, like the message says. On modern Linux the paths are often in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` and included from the main config file.

If you want to install to `/usr/lib`, you can configure with `./configure --prefix=/usr`. But this can conflict with libraries installed from package manager.

Comment: I've added /usr/local/lib to '/etc/ld.so.conf'
So why is it still showing this message?

Comment: @NobinPegasus Because it is just informational message. Libtool always prints that message when it has installed libraries.